# How can I align a fullbrowser HTML5-video background to top-left?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm using HTML5 video as background & in fullbrowser.
I've managed to align the video to center & to bottom right...
**Center align css:**

```
position:           fixed;
top:                50%;
left:               50%;
min-width:          100%;
min-height:         100%;
width:              auto;
height:             auto;
z-index:            -100;
transform:          translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform:      translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
```

**Bottom right align css:**

```
position:           fixed;
right:              0;
bottom:             0;
width:              auto;
min-width:          100%;
height:             auto;
min-height:         100%;
z-index:            -100;
```

But I can't figure out hot to align to ***top left***.
It seems like this is hard to achieve - been searching for this but haven't found any solution. Does anyone out there know how to solve this?
I'm looking for a pure css-solution.
Thanks, Niklas

Comment: did you try `top:0;left:0` ? reproduce the issue in a fiddle for us

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Chris M for taking time to answer my question.
I have tried top:0; left:0; & that doesn't work.
Part of the video is showing - seems like the lower right quarter to be more exact... 
Here is a link to a fiddle example:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kCV6/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>              
<video loop="true" id="bgvideo" preload="true" autoplay="true">
<source src="video/turn.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video/turn.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>                
</body>

#bgvideo { 
position:           fixed;
top:                50%;
left:               50%;
min-width:          100%;
min-height:         100%;
width:              auto;
height:             auto;
z-index:            -100;
transform:          translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform:      translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your definition of 'top left aligned video' is.
Remember you have two constraints:

- Constraint (i): The video must fill the entire screen.
- Constaint (ii): The video width and height ratio must be preserved.

When you need to simultaneously satisfy these two constraints, 'top left aligned' doesn't have a clear meaning. To me, the closest thing you are looking for is in option **A**.

**A.** You want video that fills the screen and furthermore, **whose left edge and right edge are never trimmed**.

```
video { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

No matter how you resize the browser window, neither the left edge of the video nor the top edge of the video is trimmed. They will always be visible. See this fiddle and try resizing the frame.

*Note: If you drag the left side of the screen, the video may look like it is 'expanding from the right', but this has to be done to ensure that the video is still filling the screen. It has to do this or else constraint (i) or constraint (ii) will be broken. Don't let this confuse you. The only other alternatives are to remove constraint (i) or constaint (ii).*

**B.** If you want (ii) but don't care about (i)

```
video { 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top:  0%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

Again the left edge and right edge are never trimmed. However some parts of the page are not covered by the video.

**C.** If you want (i) but don't care about (ii)

Not possible: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19874201/3649209
Browsers always preserve the ratio for `<video>`s.

Answer (score -1):

did you try this:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
z-index: -100;
```